# Transfer data/command to main application in a multi user environment

Tags: java

I have a java(FX) 8 main application that also has authentication and runs in a multi user environment.

On some triggers (url protocol handler, shortcuts, ...) a different application is started and needs to send data/commands to my main application. In a single user environment I can just open a port and receive the commands on that port. However in a multi user environment the port may already be in use for a different user.

How can I send the data/commands to the main applications.

I already tried a "use the username to calculate the port" approach, but this tends to conflict with ports that are already in use/are reserved.

The application should run on Windows Server 2012+.